# How can get the values of a list from a json and compare

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to get the value of a list inside a json in spring boots, I can do it by

```
    getanswersText().equalsIgnoreCase("-")
```

this is my controller

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/ordenes", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@ApiOperation(value = "Creates a parent order in pgs", notes = "Returns the creates parent order")
@ApiResponses(value ={
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success in creating the LeadParent", response = ParentLeadDto.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "You want to generate a Bucket 3 project with another service or Could not create LeadParent"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 412, message = "X-tenant-id provider is invalid or does not contain x-tenant-id provider"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error")
    })
public ResponseEntity<ParentLeadDto> createParentOrder(@ApiParam(name ="LeadParent", value = "Json ParentLeadDto for create parentOrder in PGS", required = true)@RequestBody ParentLeadDto parentOrderDto) throws OrderValidationException, SequenceException{
    ParentLeadDto parentOrderDtoResponse = leadOrderServices.createParentOrder(parentOrderDto);
    List<GenericServiceComboboxDto> list = parentOrderDto.getLstServices();

    if(parentOrderDtoResponse != null) {
        parentOrderDtoResponse.setCustomer(parentOrderDto.getCustomer());
        parentOrderDtoResponse.setLocationNode(parentOrderDto.getLocationNode());
        parentOrderDtoResponse.setLstServices(parentOrderDto.getLstServices());
        parentOrderDtoResponse.setInstallAddress(parentOrderDto.getInstallAddress());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(parentOrderDtoResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

the problem
it is necessary to go through the json in all the fields that says xxx and then evaluate its value of each one of them is equal to a "-" if so it will make a function of the rest another ...

but in the structure of the json can come several Declaration Text Text Declaration Text that are the answers of the users

What I need is to compare all the statements of text Text in its value is different from a script.

this is format json

```
    {
                "name": "Sabe el área (superficie) estimada del espacio a instalar en m2?",
                "answersText": null,
                "answersMultiple": null,
                "type": "text",
                "identificationValue": "57"
            },
            {
                "name": "Desea que los escombros sean retirados de su vivienda al finalizar los trabajos?",
                "answersText": "-",
                "answersMultiple": null,
                "type": "select",
                "identificationValue": "58"
            },
            {
                "name": "Se necesita la instalación de guardapolvos??",
                "answersText": "-",
                "answersMultiple": null,
                "type": "select",
                "identificationValue": "60"
            },
            {
                "name": "Un Instalador Experto lo contactará telefónicamente para programar una visita (cita)de presupuesto a más tardar en los próximos 2 días laborales. ¿Cuál es el mejor momento para contactarlo? (Ingrese cualquier detalle que ayude en el espacio para notas)",
                "answersText": "-",
                "answersMultiple": null,
                "type": "select",
                "identificationValue": "62"
            }
```

The business logic says if answersText != "-" do something else other something..

I am new with the frame - thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not related to Spring boot, and also can you please format the question and elaborate the problem

Comment: @Anil hi, i add new details.. thanks

Comment: @JonathanZambranocan can you please identify where is your getanswersText() method. means getanswersText() where it is inside the parentOrderDtoResponse  object ?

Comment: and that condition you can validate client side also using JSONObject convert the object in jsonobject and get the object and put the condition as per your business requirement.